# Posgres SQL- Best way to compress a table of 10 seconds entry to 1 minute entry

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a system which I record the variables values each 10s. 
However, due some technical reasons, i need to change the aquisition period to 1minute.

My question is, whats the best solution to update all table, I mean i need to delete the previews records keeping just one sample each minute and delete the records between.

I thinking in dump the table grouping by minute and import it again. create a script like in c to perform the difference calc and delete.

here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "FloatTable"
(
  "DateAndTime" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  "Millitm" integer NOT NULL,
  "TagIndex" integer NOT NULL,
  "Val" double precision,
  "Status" character(1),
  "Marker" character(1),
```

Well, can you give me your ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a large table, then using a second table is the best solution.  You don't describe the data, so it is not clear if `group by` is necessary.

Comment: Describe the table. In `psql` do a `\d my_table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the data and process into a second table.

Then delete from the first table.

Then load the data back.

Since this is a one-time job, I dont see a benefit to a full ETL toolchain.  Just do it in the db and drop the other tables when youa re done.

Comment: That was my initial idea, I was just wondering if there is other way, because i am still aquiring to the table, so I was trying to avoid to stop the aquisition

Comment: If you know the data point where you are making the switch you can do this with part of the table and insert it back in place.

Comment: Arguably this is a LOT more flexible than an ETL job in terms of avoiding a stop/rebuild/restart cycle.

Comment: This is the simplest solution (and it will not interfere with ongoing processes). In both cases, the *hard part* will be to select the observations that are closest to the minute tick-mark.